# Crawling IDs and getting TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Tags: python, string, list, beautifulsoup, typeerror

I try to get ids from a real estate website. In my first attempt i just got always the first real estate in one building project. Now i tried to go futher down the html-tree to get the rest of the building project. But im getting this error:

> "TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str"

The HTML looks like this:

```html
 "resultlist.resultlist": {
                "paging": {
                    "next": {
                        "@xlink.href": "\/Suche\/S-T\/P-2\/Wohnung-Kauf\/Nordrhein-Westfalen\/Duesseldorf\/-\/-\/-\/-\/-\/-\/-\/-\/-\/-\/-\/-\/-\/-\/-\/-\/-\/true"
                    },
                    "current": {
                        "@xlink.href": "\/Suche\/S-T\/Wohnung-Kauf\/Nordrhein-Westfalen\/Duesseldorf\/-\/-\/-\/-\/-\/-\/-\/-\/-\/-\/-\/-\/-\/-\/-\/-\/-\/true"
                    },
                    "pageNumber": 1,
                    "pageSize": 20,
                    "numberOfPages": 3,
                    "numberOfHits": 140,
                    "numberOfListings": 50
                },
                "matchCountList": "",
                "resultlistEntries": [{
                    "@numberOfHits": "140",
                    "@realEstateType": "2",
                    "resultlistEntry": [{
                        "@id": "111337199",
                        "@modification": "2019-06-09T13:36:23.513+02:00",
                        "@creation": "2019-05-05T14:10:47.000+02:00",
                        "@publishDate": "2019-05-05T14:10:47.000+02:00",
                        "similarObjects": [{
                            "similarObject": [{
                                "@id": "105147583",
                                "@modification": "2019-05-05T10:37:59.830+02:00",
                                "@creation": "2018-05-30T11:44:29.000+02:00",
                                "@publishDate": "2018-05-30T11:44:29.000+02:00",
                                "realEstateId": 105147583,
```

My First attempt looked like this:

```
page1 = ('https://www.immobilienscout24.de/Suche/S-1/Wohnung-Kauf/Nordrhein-Westfalen/Duesseldorf/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/true')
res_page1 = requests.get(page1)
soup_page1 = bs(res_page1.content, 'lxml')
r_page1 = re.compile(r'resultListModel:(.*)')
data_page1 = soup_page1.find('script', text=r_page1).text
script_page1 = r_page1.findall(data_page1)[0].rstrip(',')
results_page1 = json.loads(script_page1)
ids_page1 = [item["@id"] for item in results_page1['searchResponseModel']['resultlist.resultlist']['resultlistEntries'][0]['resultlistEntry']]
```

And got this output:

```
['111353960', '110253440', '111994208', '110517626', '109984070', '109855231', '108761945', '108639776', '106997219', '106492496', '111604737', '111357085', '92741038', '112031279', '111988597', '111876292', '111870285', '111798416', '110742328', '110742299']
```

Now i went down to get the rest as well like this:

```
ids_page1 = [item["@id"] for item in results_page1['searchResponseModel']['resultlist.resultlist']['resultlistEntries']['resultlistEntry']['similarObjects'][0]['similarObject']]
```

And now Im getting the Type Error.

Could someome please explain what i am doing wrong.

Comment: For the first item returned with id 109793951, what would be the expected other id/ids?

Comment: no that would be too much, i just need a list with all of them inside.
if i do it like the first attempt and get the top level id and then in a second run the similarobject ids thats fine as well. I just need all of them to build the URLs with the IDs in a second step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following which goes through the levels

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs #4.7.1
import requests

page1 = 'https://www.immobilienscout24.de/Suche/S-1/Wohnung-Kauf/Nordrhein-Westfalen/Duesseldorf/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/true'
res_page1 = requests.get(page1)
soup_page1 = bs(res_page1.content, 'lxml')
r_page1 = re.compile(r'resultListModel:(.*)')
data_page1 = soup_page1.find('script', text=r_page1).text
script_page1 = r_page1.findall(data_page1)[0].rstrip(',')
results_page1 = json.loads(script_page1)
ids = []

for item in results_page1['searchResponseModel']['resultlist.resultlist']['resultlistEntries'][0]['resultlistEntry']:
    ids.append(item['@id'])
    if 'similarObjects' in item:
        for i in item['similarObjects'][0]['similarObject']:
            if isinstance(i,dict):
                ids.append(i['@id'])
            elif i == '@id':
                ids.append(item['similarObjects'][0]['similarObject'][i])
```

Comment: Hey i think i put the wrong link into the example, thats the right one: "https://www.immobilienscout24.de/Suche/S-1/Wohnung-Kauf/Nordrhein-Westfalen/Duesseldorf/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/true"

In the first attempt Im just getting the first real estate of each project. 
In the second one i wanna get all other real estate of each project.
In your solution im getting the surrouding suburbs.

Comment: can you provide an example of the other ids you expect to return?

Comment: From the HTML-example above Im getting with the first attempt just: this ID 111337199.
But I would like to get this one "105147583" as well.

Answer (score 0):

In the output, you see a list of strings. Note the `'` surrounding the values.
Call `int(s)` on a string of digits to turn it into a number.

Comment: Okay thanks, two questions: first where do i have to put the int() around. and second what am i doing diffrentlyto the first try where i dont get an error? for me it seems like i just go down the html tree in the same logic than before but now getting an error and have to convert the value.